# How to get xml tag which has value and the value in C# for smart?

Tags: c#, xml

In the following xml, I'd like to get drive0 and drive1.

```
<Config>
 <Name>AAAA</Name>
 <drive0>C:/Temp</drive0>
 <drive1>//192.168.1.1/Test</drive1>
 <drive2></drive2>
</Config>
```

I wrote the following codes but this is not smart. I am not obsessed with linq.

```
String configPath = "config.xml";
XElement loadedConfig = XElement.Load(configPath);

IEnumerable<String> infos = from item in loadedConfig.Elements("drive0")
                                        select item.Value;
IEnumerable<String> infos = from item in loadedConfig.Elements("drive1")
                                        select item.Value;
IEnumerable<String> infos = from item in loadedConfig.Elements("drive2")
                                        select item.Value;
```

I changed the code below based on the answer.

```
var DrivePaths = new Dictionary<string, string>()
for (int i =0; i < 3; i++)
{
   string DrivePathNum = "studyDrivePath_" + i.ToString();
   string DrivePath = loadedConfig.Descendants(DrivePathNum).FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
   studyDrivePaths.Add(DrivePathNum, sDrivePath);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string configPath = "e:\temp\config.xml";
    XDocument loadedConfig = XDocument.Load(configPath);

    string drive0 = loadedConfig.Descendants("drive0").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
    string drive1 = loadedConfig.Descendants("drive1").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
}
```